# Нужно привязать клавижу клавиатуры к button с помощью javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Мне нужно привязать клавишу клавиатуры к `button`, чтобы при нажатии она активировалась, и происходило какое-то действие.

Вот код:

```
<div class="box-container">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-1">1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-1">2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-1">3</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-1">4</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-1">5</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-1">6</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-1">7</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-1">8</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Вас точно неустроит штатный для html accesskey={клавиша}

Comment: Нет, не устроит

Answer (score 0):

Можно отлавливать события клавиатуры и триггерить нужную кнопку.

```js
const btn1 = document.getElementById('btn-1');
const btn2 = document.getElementById('btn-2');
const btn3 = document.getElementById('btn-3');

btn1.addEventListener('click', () => alert(1));
btn2.addEventListener('click', () => alert(2));
btn3.addEventListener('click', () => alert(3));

window.addEventListener('keypress', event => {
  switch (event.keyCode) {
    case 49: btn1.click();
      break;
    case 50: btn2.click();
      break;
    case 51: btn3.click();
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="btn-1" type="button">1</button>
<button id="btn-2" type="button">2</button>
<button id="btn-3" type="button">3</button>
```